# Highlevel interface to PDF-Generation

Tags: java, pdf

I need to generate PDF-documents with java. I've tried with iTextPDF, and with ApachePDFbox.  I have the impression, these are libraries to do all possible things with PDF.

But I only have a few requirements:

- create a PDF-document from Scratch
- add chapters having a title
- adding plain text to a chapter
- adding text from HTML to a chapter
- adding an image to the chapter, being scaled to fit if needed
- adding a table to the chapter
- create a header and a footer
- having a background image

There is quite a learning curve to do these things with the libraries mentioned above. So I'm dreaming of a high level API making my life much easier, having these few methods:

- createChapter(String title)
- addPlainText(Chapter chapter,String text)
- addHtml(Chapter chapter,String html)
- addImage(Chapter chapter,byte[] bytes)  (because it's coming out of the DB)
- addTable(Chapter chapter, TableModel table)
- addHeader(HeaderFooterModel header)
- addFooter(HeaderFooterModel footer)
- addBackGroundImage(Chapter chapter,byte[] bytes)

Is there something like that already available? This would be cool and safe some time.

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: The PDFBox API doesn't seem all that difficult to me. See the "hello world" example here: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/HelloWorld.java?view=markup. Having said that, if you want to add HTML to a PDF document, perhaps consider Apache FOP: this is a library for converting XSL-FO text to PDF (and others). If you have well-formed HTML, converting it to a passage of XSL-FO is not difficult.

Comment: *The PDFBox API doesn't seem all that difficult to me.* Wow, is that for real, @KevinBoone or are you just pulling the OP's leg? With PDFBox, you have to calculate the position of every piece of text (e.g. `contents.newLineAtOffset(100, 700);`) That is pretty low-level, whereas the OP asked for a high-level approach.

Comment: My comment wasn't intended to be glib; whether specifying the position of text is a problem depends on the kind of layout you are trying to create, doesn't it? If you want complete auto-layout of text, I would suggest FOP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following class is a great start at having a very high level API for iText.
I implemented most of the methods you requested.
The remainder is left as a challenge to the reader.

```
package stackoverflow;

import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter;
import com.itextpdf.io.image.ImageDataFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.color.Color;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.color.DeviceRgb;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.IBlockElement;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.IElement;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Image;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class ITextForDummiesFacade 
{

    // iText IO
    private PdfDocument pdfDocument;
    private Document layoutDocument;

    // font sizes
    private float regularFontSize = 12f;
    private float chapterTitleFontSize = 14f;

    // font colors
    private Color chapterFontColor = new DeviceRgb(249, 157, 37);
    private Color regularFontColor = new DeviceRgb(100, 100, 100);

    // structure
    private Map<String, Integer> chapterNames = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<Integer, List<IElement>> elementsPerChapter = new HashMap<>();

    public ITextForDummiesFacade(OutputStream os) throws IOException 
    {
        this.pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(os));
        this.layoutDocument  = new Document(pdfDocument);
    }

    public ITextForDummiesFacade(File outputFile) throws IOException 
    {
        this.pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outputFile));
        this.layoutDocument  = new Document(pdfDocument);
    }

    public boolean createChapter(String title)
    {
        if(chapterNames.containsKey(title))
            return false;
        int nextID = chapterNames.size();
        chapterNames.put(title, nextID);
        elementsPerChapter.put(nextID, new ArrayList<IElement>());
        elementsPerChapter.get(nextID).add(new Paragraph(title)
            .setFontSize(chapterTitleFontSize)
            .setFontColor(chapterFontColor));
        return true;
    }

    public boolean addPlainText(String chapter, String text)
    {
        if(!chapterNames.containsKey(chapter))
            return false;
        int ID = chapterNames.get(chapter);
        elementsPerChapter.get(ID).add(new Paragraph(text)
            .setFontSize(regularFontSize)
            .setFontColor(regularFontColor));
        return true;
    }

    public boolean addHTML(String chapter, String HTML)
    {
        if(!chapterNames.containsKey(chapter))
            return false;
        int ID = chapterNames.get(chapter);
        try 
        {
    elementsPerChapter.get(ID).addAll(HtmlConverter.convertToElements(HTML));
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean addImage(String chapter, byte[] image)
    {
        if(!chapterNames.containsKey(chapter))
            return false;
        int ID = chapterNames.get(chapter);
        elementsPerChapter.get(ID).add(new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(image)));
        return true;
    }

    private void write()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<chapterNames.size();i++)
        {
            for(IElement e : elementsPerChapter.get(i))
                if(e instanceof IBlockElement)
                    layoutDocument.add((IBlockElement) e);
        }
    }

    public void close()
    {
        write();
        layoutDocument.flush();
        layoutDocument.close();
    }
}
```

You can then easily call this facade to do the work for you.

```
    File outputFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "output.pdf");

    ITextForDummiesFacade facade = new ITextForDummiesFacade(outputFile);
    facade.createChapter("Chapter 1");
    facade.addPlainText("Chapter 1","Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.");
    facade.close();
```

Comment: This was written in less than half an hour. So I would argue that iText is pretty easy to use. Most of the work was setting up a datastructure that allows you to add content by chapter, rather than in a linear flow.

Comment: Many thanks for this help. I've implemented it to my project and all went fine, Except the HTML-converter asked for a license. This is where I' failed. As an alternative I'm giving a try to Apache FOP

Comment: pdfHTML is being open sourced this sprint. Your patience shall be rewarded. And until then you can always use a trial license. Unless you intend to use this for a commercial purpose. Then you should get a license.